# The Envelope of Rotating Ellipses Around Their Focus: Part II

Tags: geometry

Find another envelope (other than the line parallel to $y$-axis) in the animation given by Blue [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542453/rotating-ellipse-envelope#1542523).

Answer (score 1):

Another cardoid envelope appears associated as tangent to the first vertical envelope.

$$ r(\theta, \alpha ) = a\;\frac{- e \cos(\theta+ \alpha )+ \sqrt{ 1 - e^2 \sin^2(\theta+\alpha)}}{(1 - e)(1 - e \cos \alpha)} $$

$$ (x,y)= r(\theta, \alpha ) ( \cos \theta ,\sin \theta )$$

[image: Rotating Ellipse Envelope 2]

Comment posted here to include image of a fuller envelope. Request for comments whether this manner of modification is correct or appropriate.

Comment: I got something similar, although I'm not happy with the form of the equation I have.