# Envelope of an Envelope

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

**Background and Motivation**

Consider the following equation of family of ellipses in polar coordinates

$$ r(\theta, \alpha ) = a\;\frac{- e \cos(\theta+ \alpha )+ \sqrt{ 1 - e^2 \sin^2(\theta+\alpha)}}{(1 - e)(1 - e \cos \alpha)} $$

where $r$ and $\theta$ are usual polar coordinates and $e$ is the eccentricity of the ellipse. This equation describes a family of ellipses which are rotated around their focus by angle $\alpha$ such that $x= \dfrac{a}{1-e}$ is their envelope. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542453/rotating-ellipse-envelope-1#1542523) for the derivation of the equation by BLUE. The following animation given by BLUE helps to imagine better

[image]

The above set of expanding/contacting ellipses rotating about their focus was constructed by BLUE to have a single horizontal envelope . However, another envelope is found for this family of curves in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542621/rotating-ellipse-envelope-2), which was not envisaged at the outset, (not bargained for). The second blue line in the following picture shows the second envelope.

[image]

---

**Question**

Under what circumstances do we have an envelope for an envelope described by a single parameter/geometrical constant in such a set of smooth curves?

EDIT1:

Depicting the two parameter ($\epsilon$ and rotation) set of x-axis touching ellipses.

Second part of ellipse expansion after further upward expansion of major axis is omitted ,can be implemented later.

In the polar focal form there are  *two* constants, $ \epsilon ,\, p $ the eccentricity and semi-latus rectum.

There are many ways of doing it.

1) Keep $p$ same, vary $\epsilon$.

2) Keep $\epsilon$ same,vary $p$.

3) Choose an arbitrary function connecting them.

Choice is for first option.

To touch a pre-fixed envelope Y = 5 the ellipse hinges about focus and droops by an angle:

$$ = \cos^{-1}\frac{Q}{2 e p Y}; \, Q^2 = 2 p^2 Y^2 (1+ e^2) - Y^2 (1-e)^2 $$

( polar coordinates) radius at tangential contact is given by:

$$ r_{T} = \frac{2 p Y^2}{p^2 +Y^2(1-e^2)} $$

Constants for above set of ellipses are  $ (a =5, b=3, e =0.8, Y= 5.) $

It is however noted that the envelope appears as desired and that there is *no envelope of envelope.*

[image]

Comment: Can you please add more explanation and details to your question? :) Also, giving a summary of the related linked posts can help others to understand this question better! :) I think this is a nice question which is not expressed well (+1).

Comment: I saw that there is a vote to close so I decided to edit the question. Please take a look at the edit too see if it exactly contains what you mean. :)

Comment: Fine and  thanks soo much!

Comment: Do you think that we have a family of envelopes for these family of ellipses and these family of envelopes will have another envelope? :) Did I get you right? :)

Comment: I think there is still some ambiguity in the question!  **envelope of an envelope** is meaningless since envelope is defined for a family of curves. Hence, this can be meaningful only when we say **envelope of a family of envelopes**.

Comment: perhaps no such arbitrarily generated grandchildren.Must go over topics $ tac/,locus, cusp/,locus $ in textbooks

Comment: I didn't get you! :) Was my thought true about your question? What do you mean by **envelope of an envelope**? Is this terminology standard?

Comment: @H.R. The mod may show us to chat-room. This terminology is not standard. Only when a proper differential equation is set up eliminating the dilation constant will all your questions be answered, Maybe with your background (wanting to unify $w, \psi $ in pde) you can handle it.

Comment: Why don't you put a bounty on the question so you can attract more attention? :)